# Best practices in ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms Url Rewriting (Mask URL address link)

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, url-rewriting, url-masking

What are the methods and best practices for URL Rewriting (Masking URL) in ASP.NET 4.0?

We have an ASP.NET 4 Website and when testing on the client he wanted to hide or simplify our URL addresses, meaning he wants querystrings and url paths of the server to hide.

How can I achieve something like this in ASP.NET 4 Web Forms?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IIS module to achieve this

http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

Comment: Thank you and Kishanu, Lumi as well, I will see what fits and works for my scenario and feedback to all, mark an answer etc.

Answer (score -2):

In asp.net 4 u can use Asp.Net Routing.
Please visit [MSDN : ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)
Hope it helps. Good Luck.